# What's the best server side web framework for developer productivity?

Tags: java, iphone, django, orm

I have to select a web framework for a web 2.0 application that may have millions of web users (i.e. must scale reasonably) and iphone / android apps (i.e. must have good separation of concerns). What framework will allows developers to get their work done fastest? I realise this can quickly become a religious question, so I'm looking for specific evidence from people who have developed multiple projects from start to end in different systems and can compare them from a development speed perspective.

Java + something? Perhaps Groovy? Django / python? PHP? Other? How do systems with ORMs differ from systems without in terms of code development time?

Comment: I would suggest you to search the stackoverflow. there are several similar questions/answers already

Comment: Often its the one you are most familar with. ;)

Answer (score 3):

It really depends what your developers are familiar with and feel is the best fit for the project.

Comment: +1.  Learning a new framework will take time for any developer, no matter how advanced.  At least one project will be spent learning just what they *can* do, and only some knowledge will be gained on what they *should* do.  Unless the development area is new for them in general, you should probably pick a technology they are familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

If you want massive scalability but don't want to build your own IT center then you could look into Google app engine: http://code.google.com/appengine/